# Heroku : Edit file without edit on github

Tags: heroku

I have a discord bot on heroku and I am using automatic deployment with github. I have a .json data file and I am trying to write data to it, but it doesn't seem to work. I guess this takes my data file straight from github and therefore remains empty. On my computer, it works well, I manage to write in my db.json but on heroku it does not work, I have no errors. I am using a relative path and not abosulu so I don't think the error is with my code. I don't know if I was clear
Thank you in advance

Comment: try to share some information which might be helpful. used frameworks. programming language. code snippets.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem "Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.  For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management."